# AWS Lambda - security token expired exception on performance testing, changed code - not working

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I have an AWS Lambda function which connects to dynamo db (cross-account) using sts.client (boto3 python).

It does a simple task of fetching data based on a query. This code works absolutely fine almost all the time.

However, we find it failing strangely during performance tests.

For example :
Testcase 1 : we tried 75 calls to the api per min for 1 hr. Consistently it fails at somewhere around 55 - 57th min with bad gateway errors.

However,sometimes after Testcase1 and sometimes before, we try a 500 calls / min  for 1 hr and this works absolutely fine with 0 bad gateway errors.

The errors we see during test case 1 : None at the api-gateway / dynamo but only at lambda logs :

`[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (ExpiredTokenException) when calling the Query  operation: The security token included in the request is expired`

So, following some StackOverflow links which suggest calling to create token from inside the main function of lambda instead of global. we changed the code, but still we see it failing.

2 Questions here :

1. Why would 75 req / min fail and a 500 req/min pass on the same instance at almost same times (tried on 2 different days, times).
2. Help required to understand why code change is not refreshing the token.

```
import json
import boto3
import os
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr
from botocore.credentials import RefreshableCredentials
from decimal import Decimal
import datetime



# Constants
ROLE_ARN = os.environ['arnrole']
ROLE_SESSION_NAME = 'dynamodb-session'
EXPIRATION_THRESHOLD_SECONDS = 3580  # Setting 5 mins check below which it will refresh token


def get_sts_token():
   # Create an STS client
   sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
   # Assume the role to get temporary credentials
   response = sts_client.assume_role(
       RoleArn=ROLE_ARN,
       RoleSessionName=ROLE_SESSION_NAME
   )
   # Extract and return temporary credentials
   print("invoked sts new")
   return response['Credentials']
   
def refresh_sts_token_if_needed(current_credentials):
   # Calculate remaining time until expiration\
   print(current_credentials)
   expiration_time = current_credentials['Expiration']
   expiration_date = expiration_time.replace(tzinfo=None)
   remaining_seconds = ( expiration_date - datetime.datetime.utcnow()).total_seconds()

   print(remaining_seconds)

   if remaining_seconds < EXPIRATION_THRESHOLD_SECONDS:
       print("inside loop for new token")
       # Refresh the STS token if it's close to expiration
       return get_sts_token()
   else:
       # Return the current credentials if they are still valid
       print("else loop")
       return current_credentials


# Get or refresh STS token
current_credentials = get_sts_token()
    
   

""" Convert Decimal to float (test demo)
    DynamoDB stores floats as Decimals and that cannot be encoded by json.dumps()   
    the data first needs to be converted to float """
    
class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Decimal):
            return float(obj)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

       
def get_a(event):
  return(event["pathParameters"]["a"])


def get_query_result(table, a):
    
    query_result_json = table.query(KeyConditionExpression=Key('a').eq(a))
    
    query_results = json.loads(json.dumps(query_result_json, cls=DecimalEncoder))
    
    return query_results


def define_api_response(query_results, account_number):
    
    json_body_error = {"ResponseMetadata" : {"Count" : [], "RequestId" : [] , "Message" : []}}
    
    # Define the status code and body of response based on query result
    if query_results["ResponseMetadata"]["HTTPStatusCode"] == 200 and query_results["Count"] > 0: 
        response = create_response_body(200, json.dumps(query_results["Items"][0]))
    elif query_results["ResponseMetadata"]["HTTPStatusCode"] == 200 and query_results["Count"] == 0: 

        response = create_response_body(404, json.dumps(query_results["Items"]))

    else:
        json_body_error["ResponseMetadata"]["Message"].append(query_results["errorMessage"])
        json_body_error["ResponseMetadata"]["RequestId"].append(query_results["ResponseMetadata"]["RequestId"])      
        response = create_response_body(query_results["ResponseMetadata"]["HTTPStatusCode"], json.dumps(json_body_error))
    
    return response


def create_response_body(statusCode, body):
    
    str_body = str(body)
    
    response = {
      "statusCode": statusCode,
      "body": str_body,
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      },
        }
    
    print(str_body)
    return response


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Use the STS token or refresh if close to expiration
    refreshed_credentials = refresh_sts_token_if_needed(current_credentials)
    
     # Dynamo client connection : 
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name="us-east-1",aws_access_key_id=refreshed_credentials['AccessKeyId'],aws_secret_access_key=refreshed_credentials['SecretAccessKey'], aws_session_token=refreshed_credentials['SessionToken'] )

    
    # Rest of the code
    
    a = get_a(event)
    
    table = dynamodb.Table(os.environ['tablename'])
    
    query_results = get_query_result(table, account_number)
    
    response  = define_api_response(query_results, account_number)
    
    return response
```